# Powershell: Need to convert variable encoding

Tags: datetime, powershell, character-encoding

I have been working on a Powershell script to get all `6008` events (unexpected shutdown) from an event log. I then have parsed `$_.Message` to get the date and time of shutdown, and I'm trying to convert this to `[datetime]`. However, I can't format the date using `ParseExact` because there are hidden characters in the date/time (they look like hollow squares before each month, day, and year value in the date). I'm guessing this is an encoding issue; what's the best way to convert a variable to plain text (ascii? UTF8?) so that I can format this string as `[datetime]`?

Script:

```
$timefmt = "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
$Messages = (get-eventlog -LogName System -ComputerName svr-name |   Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6008 -AND $_.timegenerated -gt (get-date).adddays(-35) }|     select message)
$Messages | ForEach-Object { 
$Matched = $_.Message -match "([0-9]{1,2}:.*[0-9]{4})"
if ($Matched) {
    $SplitMatches = $Matches[1].split(" ")
    $time,$ampm,$on,$date = $SplitMatches
    $td = "$date $time $ampm
    [datetime]::ParseExact($td,$timefmt,$null)
}
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

`[datetime]::ParseExact([ascii]$td,$timefmt,$null)`

But this isn't correct, and I'm not even sure ascii is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the hidden character in the message HEX 3F, but we can account for that in the RegEx, and get past it. I used 4 capturing groups, and ended up joining the last 3 to make the date excluding the hidden characters.

I'm not used to how you do your matching, so I formatted it a little differently. I also used -After on the Get-EventLog cmdlet instead of filtering afterwards since filtering at the provider is considerably faster in general.

```
$timefmt = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
$Messages = get-eventlog -LogName System -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-35) |   Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6008 }| select -expand message
$Messages |?{$_ -match "(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2} (?:A|P)M) on .(\d{1,2}/).(\d{1,2}/).(\d{4})"}| ForEach-Object { 
        $Time = $Matches[1]
        $Date = $Matches[2..4] -join ""
        [datetime]::ParseExact("$Date $Time",$timefmt,$null)
}
```